# Semidefinite relaxation

Tags: semidefinite-programming, binary-programming, relaxations

Suppose that we have an objective function that involves two binary variables, i.e.
 $x, y \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ ($x$ represents the assignment of category A to category B and $y$ represents the assignment of Category A to category C that is different from category B) that are multiplied by each other.

Can such problems be relaxed using semidefinite programming? I know that if $x$ is multiplied by itself like in $x^T Qx$ can be relaxed but if we have a different variable like $y$: is it still possible to be relaxed?

Comment: Do you mean you want to minimize $xy$ where both are binary ?

Comment: What is the objective function?

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear if you are asking about the semidefinite relaxation of binary condition in general, or semidefinite relaxation of bilinear products of binary variables.

Bilinear products you have already in the expression $x^TQx$ which you refer to so obviously yes.

Binary constraint simply means you have the quadratic constraint $x_i(1-x_i) = 0$, which you thus incorporate in your semidefinite relaxation as any other polynomial constraint.

Comment: you mean $x^TQy$, right ?

Comment: No. $x$ is a vector, leading to  bilinear and quadratic products $x_ix_j$ when you work with quadratic expressions. The  question is confusing as it first appear to reference to $x$ and $y$ as scalars, but then $x$ is a vector when  talking about $x^TQx$.

Comment: I agree that it is confusing. But also quantities of the form $x^T Q y$ are referred to as bilinear, right ? .. look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form

Comment: Yes but it adds no value here. From the question it appears the poster is familiar with relaxation of general quadratic expressions, and then it should be clear that bilinear expressions automatically are supported as that simply means the matrix $Q$ has some zeros.

Comment: ah yes you're right $+1$ :)

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments

Comment: The objective function is $f(x,y)=\sum_w \sum_b \sum_s v^s y_{wb}x_w^s$

Comment: y and x are the decision variables and they are binary. How such problems can be relaxed using semidefine programming

Comment: v, s, w, b are parameters.

Comment: Well, if $x$ is binary, taking it to the power of $s>0$ makes no difference as $x^s$ is equal to $x$, and thus you have bilinear and it fits perfectly into standard theory of semidefinite relaxations of quadratic problems

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: what if x and y are of different sizes? My x is a matrix of 34*3 and y is a matrix of 34*158. I am not sure if we still can write the problem as $x^TQy$

Comment: Just call all your variables $z$ and you have bilinear terms $z_iz_j$ and nothing else. Your so called $x$ variables are the first 34*3 elements of that vector, and your $y$ vector would be the final 34*158 elements, and everything can be written as $z^THz$ where $H$ has $\frac{1}{2}Q$ and $\frac{1}{2}Q^T$ suitably placed in the off-diagonal blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a question: Is it possible to relax a non convex function using semidefinite programming? My domain is only 0 - 1 so the objective is not convex.

Comment: Yes, isn't that precisely what we are talking about (assuming we talk about polynomials)

Comment: Do you have any idea which programming languages can solve such problems?

Comment: Programming languages do not solve problems. Are you asking about solvers?  Then you have the standard semidefinite programming solvers (with mosek being the currently strongst choice). In practice though, the problems become intractable unless you develop some specialized solver for your particular problem. Solving MILPs using semidefinite relaxations will almost always be much much slower than simply using a strong MILP solver.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. If solving MILPs using semidefinite relaxation will be much slower than using strong MILP solvers, then what is the benefit to relax the problem using SDP?

Comment: In very structured cases where you can do clever additional stuff to get tractable problems (symmetry exploitation etc) or when you're not really interested in solving the problem but more interested in deriving bounds on the solution or combinations of these. A random example is the results on kissing numbers etc by Bachoc & Vallentin